Iconography of Dhattatreya
There is some controversy regarding the depiction of Dhattatreya. Sri Vaishnavas say that he is a Tridhandi Sannyasi. Madhwas are saying he is not a Sannyasi. While his present inconography shows him with 3 heads 4 dogs and a cow. What is the inconography of him described in texts.

I) Markandeya purana says that the Prajāpati Atri begot three sons by his wife Anasūyā, namely, Soma, Dattātreya, and, Durvāsas, who were incarnations of portions of Brahmā, Viṣṇu and Śiva respectively. Moreover, Dattātreya(दत्तात्रेय) has been described in the same purana as:

Dattātreya, assembling young Munis about himself, tested their loyalty,
by living immersed in a lake and by revelling in sensual pleasures.
 
-Markandeya purana: Canto XVII


II) Sri Datta Vaibhavam website says about Pratimālakṣaṇa (प्रतिमालक्षण/Iconography):

The trinity represent his three faces, his body is pure chit, the six
branches of knowledge are his six hands, the four dogs are the four
Vedas, the cow is Dharma, universal peace is the Udumbara tree
(उदुम्बर वृक्षः) and the great incarnation of Brahman, complete with
sixteen kalas, which is a personification of the knowledge of the Self
– is the unfathomable Murti of Sri Dattātreya.
-Sri Datta Vaibhavam website.

III) Vishnudharmottara Purana(विष्णुधर्मोत्तर महापुराण) says about Pratimālakṣaṇa(प्रतिमालक्षण/Iconography) as follows:
Vālmīki should be fair and almost hidden, from sight by the circle of matted locks. 
Calm and engaged in asceticism, he is neither lean nor plump.

One should give to Dattātreya all the marks of Vālmīki.

-Vishnudharmottara Purana: Part-III, Ch-85, Verses 1-79. 

Your question There is some controversy regarding the depiction of Dhattatreya. Sri Vaishnavas say that he is a Tridhandi Sannyasi. Madhwas are saying he is not a Sannyasi.
From Vishnudharmottara Purana [Part-III, Ch-85, Verses 1-79], Dattātreya, having all the marks of Vālmīki, has been considered as a Rishi. Therefore, the description of "Tridhandi Sannyāsi" or "He is not a Sannyāsi" should be set aside safely!
Good Luck!

I didn't get your last part of the answer. Are you saying he is not a Tridhandi?

Yes, since Dattātreya has all the marks of Vālmīki, according to Vishnudharmottara Purana, like Vālmīki,, he should be carrying a Brahma Danda only. My assertion is based on this purana alone. However, most of the images, Dattātreya appears to be with Tridhandi but there is no scriptural evidence to support that view.

bruh I think you misunderstood my question. Dhattatreya is not portrayed as a Tridhandi. Sri Vaishanavas are saying this iconography is wrong and he should be portrayed as one.

Then, let them produce scriptural evidence to support that view. You and me will have not problem in accepting Dhattatreya is a Tridhandi upon production of such evidence!
